# Pivot in HSQLDB without using JOINs

Tags: sql, pivot, hsqldb

Im using a **HSLQDB** (2.2.9) database which I connect to via java JDBC.

Person A has received vaccinations 1 and 3, person B has received 2 and 4.
Using this simple query:

```
SELECT std.*,vac.Date FROM Students AS std
LEFT JOIN ValuesVaccination AS vac
ON vac.ID_Students = std.ID
```

I get a result set like:

```
 ID |  Name    | ID_Vaccination | Date
 1  | PersonA  | 1              | 2011-06-01
 1  | PersonA  | 3              | 2012-03-21
 1  | PersonB  | 2              | 2012-08-11
 2  | PersonB  | 4              | 2012-09-08
```

What I want to get is:

```
 ID |  Name    | Vaccination1 | Vaccination2 | Vaccination3 | Vaccination4  
 1  | PersonA  |  2011-06-01  |    NULL      |  2012-03-21  |    NULL
 2  | PersonB  |    NULL      |  2012-08-11  |    NULL      |  2012-09-08
```

One way to do this is:

```
SELECT std.*,
       vac1.Date AS "Vaccination1",
       vac2.Date AS "Vaccination2",
       vac3.Date AS "Vaccination3",
       vac4.Date AS "Vaccination4"
FROM Students AS std
LEFT JOIN ValuesVaccination AS vac1
ON vac1.ID_Students = std.ID AND vac1.ID_Vaccinations = 1
LEFT JOIN ValuesVaccination AS vac2
ON vac2.ID_Students = std.ID AND vac2.ID_Vaccinations = 2
LEFT JOIN ValuesVaccination AS vac3
ON vac3.ID_Students = std.ID AND vac3.ID_Vaccinations = 3
LEFT JOIN ValuesVaccination AS vac4
ON vac4.ID_Students = std.ID AND vac4.ID_Vaccinations = 4
```

The problem is the **number of different vaccinations is variable**. Is there a decent way to do this without building the query with the JOINs in a java String using a loop?

I figured out the **PIVOT** function is what I need, but it seems HSQLDB does not support it and searching stackoverflow and google did not bring up useful information.

Thank you for any information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PIVOT` is not standard SQL, it's an extension to syntax supported only by [Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (and later), and [Oracle 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html).

Here's a solution that uses standard SQL and should work in any RDBMS:

```
SELECT s.ID, s.Name, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Vaccination=1 THEN Date END) AS Vaccination1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Vaccination=2 THEN Date END) AS Vaccination2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Vaccination=3 THEN Date END) AS Vaccination3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Vaccination=4 THEN Date END) AS Vaccination4
FROM Students AS s
LEFT JOIN ValuesVaccination AS v
  ON s.ID = v.ID_Students
GROUP BY s.ID, s.Name;
```

---

Re your comment:

SQL does not allow data values to generate new columns dynamically in the same query.  So
*any* pivot query requires that you know how many distinct vaccinations you want to show in the output before you prepare the query.

You could run two queries:  one to "discover" the set of distinct vaccination values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_Vaccination FROM ValuesVaccination;
```

Then fetch that back into the application and loop over it, adding column expressions as you go, to build the pivot query.

The only alternative is to fetch *all* the data joined to Students, as in your first query, and post-process it into a pivoted format using application code.

Either way, to produce a dynamic pivot query you have to supplement it with application code, either before you prepare the query or after you fetch the results.

Comment: What if there are 10 different vaccinations? Or 30? They can be created and deleted by the application user

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the `MAX` function is exactly what I need since there can be several values and I need to display the most recent date.

Comment: `PIVOT` is also supported by Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @a_horse_with_no_name!  I have edited the above and added links.

Answer (score 0):

There is just one bracket too much after the `END)` in Bill's answer.
To have a 100% correct answer in this thread using the alias and column names from the original question:

```
SELECT std.ID, std.Name, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.ID_Vaccinations=1 THEN Date END) AS Vaccination1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.ID_Vaccinations=2 THEN Date END) AS Vaccination2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.ID_Vaccinations=3 THEN Date END) AS Vaccination3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.ID_Vaccinations=4 THEN Date END) AS Vaccination4
FROM Students AS std
LEFT JOIN ValuesVaccination AS v
ON std.ID = v.ID_Students
GROUP BY std.ID, std.Name
```

returns the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer to fix the imbalanced parens.